# Github get committed changes

Tags: git, github, commit

How do I get these changes from github on my Mac OSX?

https://github.com/ettore/three20/commit/63d03a12a6aac60453c94c12d714965aaca810ae

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fetch a copy of the `ettore/three20` repository in that exact state with `git`:

```
# Create a new (empty) repo
git clone https://github.com/ettore/three20.git

# Enter repo
cd three20

# Checkout the commit
git checkout 63d03a12a6aac60453c94c12d714965aaca810ae
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get this commit changes from github by [THIS API](http://developer.github.com/v3/git/commits/):

```
GET /repos/:user/:repo/git/commits/:sha
```

An example of the one you gave:

```
curl -i https://api.github.com/repos/ettore/three20/commits/63d03a12a6aac60453c94c12d714965aaca810ae > commit_changes
```

Then you can view the total data in the `commit_changes` file that generated. The format of this file is JSON, and you'll find the changes in `"patch"`, like:

> "patch": "@@ -38,6 +38,12 @@\n static const NSInteger kLoadMaxRetries = 2;\n \n \n+@interface TTRequestLoader ()\n+- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;\n+- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data;\n+- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection;\n+@end\n+\n ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////\n ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////\n ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////\n@@ -100,7 +106,8 @@ - (void)deliverDataResponse:(NSURL*)URL {\n     // Strictly speaking, to be really conformant need to interpret %xx hex encoded entities.\n     // The [NSString dataUsingEncoding] doesn't do that correctly............(omission)

You can find that it's hard to read, but you can format it better with `Regular Expression` if you can. Apparently, the lines that added/removed with the start of `+`/`-` and end of `\n`.

You can run this command in your `vim`(if you use):

```
:%s/\\n/^M/g
```

this one replace every `\n` to a real newline(`^M` is entered by `Ctrl+v`->`Enter`). It looks well now, but I think you can do better. ;)

Note: you'll get lots useless datas if your changes include some binary file(like a icon.png).